# Space in grails GSP

Tags: jsp, grails, gsp

Sorry grails / gsp noob here. I am trying to fix a bug where a space is always inserted before some text.

The text is just displayed based on a else if:

```
<g:elseif test="${index > 0 && merch <= transaction.Transactions.size() - 2}">
, ${trans.name}
</g:elseif>
```

A space is always displayed before the comman.  Why? How do I get rid of the space?

Answer (score 4):

> Why?

Because there's white space (the newline) between the opening `elseif` tag and the comma.

> How do I get rid of the space?

Put the comma directly after the opening tag rather than on the next line.  You can achieve this by moving the newline inside the tag rather than after it:

```
<g:elseif test="${index > 0 && merch <= transaction.Transactions.size() - 2}"
  >, ${trans.name}</g:elseif>
```

or by using a comment

```
<g:elseif test="${index > 0 && merch <= transaction.Transactions.size() - 2}"><%--
  --%>, ${trans.name}<%--
--%></g:elseif>
```

You may find you need to use a similar trick to squash the space between the `</g:if>` and the `<g:elseif>` tags, and immediately before the `<g:if>`.  If this all starts to look a bit unwieldy you may prefer to use Groovy code rather than GSP tags for the conditionals

```
stuff before<%
if(something) {
  %>some content<%
} else if(index > 0 && merch <= transaction.Transactions.size() - 2) {
  %>, ${trans.name}<%
} else {
  %>something else<%
}
%>
```

Comment: haven't notice it until now, but is there better way without pollute the code?